# Executing procedure in plsql developer

Tags: plsql, procedure, plsqldeveloper

I am totally new to PLSQL and I am struggling to execute a procedure in PLSQL Developer. I have created a procedure named as 'employee' as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE employee IS
    var_name VARCHAR2(20) := 'Parkavi';
    var_web VARCHAR2(20) := 'parkavi.com';
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hi! I am ' ||var_name|| 'from' ||var_web);
END employee;
```

Now I need to execute this procedure so that I can view the output. Please help me out. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you need to test this procedure, just open new sql window and invoke it, like "begin employee; end;". The output can be seen in "Output" tab. Or you can right click on the procedure and select "Test". By the way, try to stick with "good naming" practice.

Comment: @Ychdziu Still my output tab is empty and my procedure looks empty as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PL/SQL Developer, you execute PL/SQL blocks in the Test Window.

File > New > Test Window will provide a template block something like this:

```
declare 
begin

end;
```

You just need to add your procedure name (and remove the unneeded `declare` section as you have no variables), so it's:

```
begin
    employee;
end;
```

Alternatively, right-click on the procedure name and select 'Test' from the pop-up menu, and it will generate the above block for you.

If the expected `dbms_output` text is not displayed in the 'Output' tab, the first thing to check is that the 'Enabled' checkbox is checked.

[image]

To diagnose dbms_output, the simplest test case would be just:

```
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Hello');
end;
```

Comment: still I am not getting anything in the DBMS Output tab in the test window. Please tell me where can I find that 'Enabled' checkbox?

Comment: I don't get any output even though the 'Enabled' checkbox is checked

Comment: Does the Test window contents look like my example? i.e. `begin` followed by your procedure name, followed by a `;` and then `end;`?

Comment: Are you definitely executing it?

Comment: What do you mean by executing? Sorry I have no idea about that! I just typed
" begin
  employee;
end; "
and checked for output in the DBMS Output tab.

Comment: You need to run it, same as you would run a SQL query. By default it's F8, or there is a tool in the menu bar.

Comment: Even the F8 button does not work. What is the tool that I can find in the menu bar to run the command?

Comment: Sorry but this is drifting off topic. If you are not able to find the 'Execute' button or run anything then you need to check the documentation that came with the product. The button looks like either a cog wheel or a green triangle depending on the version you have.

Comment: Finally it worked. I had some logging issues and thats why I could not get the output earlier. Thanks alot for spending this much time